# Logstash : convert string to array

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash

I have csv file that has `types` column with array of integers in format:

```
id,date,state,types,x,y
14518263,2021-01-01 20:20:00,2,"18,19,63,72",14.46154,50.07164
```

Could someone help me with converting types column into array via filter in pipeline?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So I feel you need two steps for this.

You will be using 2 [mutation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) filter to do so.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        split => { "<your field name>" => "," }
    }
    mutate {
        convert => { "<your field name>" => "integer" }
    }
}
```

For reference there was a discussion going on [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/the-fliter-plugin-mutate-convert-method-only-convert-the-first-element-of-an-array/47100/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two filter for this, First, you need to split it into string array based on the splitter or seperator then you need to convert it to desired data type
here integer

```
mutate {
        split => { "field1" => "," }
        split => { "field2" => "," }
    }enter code here
    mutate {
        convert => { "field1" => "integer" }
        convert => { "field2" => "integer" }
```